Authority Key Identifier in Self Signed Certificate
I have Self Signed Certificate. This is the root certificate.
It has an extension Authority Key Identifier whose values are
KeyID=XXX
Certificate Issuer:
CN=XXX
Certificate SerialNumber=XXX
Here Certificate SerialNumber is its own serial number.
Key Id is generated using following code where certficate is nothing but its own certificate
private static void ComputeAuthorityKeyIdentifierKeyID(X509Certificate2 certificate)
{
RSA privateKey = certificate.GetRSAPrivateKey()!;
byte[] publicKeyHash = MD5.Create().ComputeHash(privateKey.ExportSubjectPublicKeyInfo());
Console.WriteLine(BitConverter.ToString(publicKeyHash).Replace("-", ""));
}
My question is before creating self signed certficate which is root certificate how to add an extension which public key and serial number  of that certificate itself
My question is before creating self signed certficate which is root certificate how to add an extension which public key and serial number  of that certificate itself
